# How to increase "scoring timeout" on ML script in Azure Container Instance?

Tags: azure, containers

I'm working on an ML model that is running in an Azure Container Instance (ACI).  I can connect with the container and the init() function runs, but the 'scoring' function is timing out (I think); its default is 60 seconds.  The error message shows nothing wrong, but the log ends with `"Scoring timeout is found from os.environ: 60000 ms"`.

Sixty seconds should be plenty of time for the run() function (i.e., the "scoring" function), but the init() function is a bit slow, and maybe that is included?  In any case, I'm having trouble figuring out how to increase the scoring_timeout.  It looks like it's some kind of environment variable. I tried (using the Python SDK):
`service.update(properties = {"scoring_timeout_ms":120000})` but it apparently had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the it's timing out in run() you could try setting [`run_invocation_timeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-parallel-run-step) to a higher value

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  It looks like that parameter is specific to a pipeline, which I'm not using.  I suppose I could wrap my code in a pipeline step, but I'm hoping there will be a simple answer.  I checked `os.environ` in the container and it doesn't show a 'timeout' parameter, so I'm not sure where the 60 second value is coming from.